# Set php version in CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos6

I just successfully upgraded my server php version from 5.3 to 5.6

When I run:

```
php -v
```

I get:

```
PHP 5.6.40 (cli)
```

But when I create a file write

```
echo phpInfo();
```

The php version showing is 5.3.3

How do I set the php version on phpinfo() to show 5.6

Thanks,

Comment: Do you restart your server after upgrade?

Comment: I didn't, any ideas on how to do that?,

Comment: I am using putty

Comment: just restart apache or what http server you use. sudo systemctl restart httpd

Comment: Tried but it didn't work

Comment: @stefo91 restarting the server worked but I had to use ```service httpd restart```. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
rm /usr/bin/php
ln -s /usr/bin/php56 /usr/bin/php
service httpd restart
```

And then run

```
php -v
```